# When i Click Back Button in android i want to make changes in previous activity?

Tags: android

When I click back button in my app I want to change some data in previous activity.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Log.v("Back Button ","Pressed");
    }
```

I am trying to using this but cant help it out ?
do I need to maintain backstack of activities which back button internally does?pls help
i want to change menubar images (wriiten by me bottom of every activty in my app) item which is present in every activty but when I click menubar (clickable) it is not able to change menubar images as per activity changes.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at `startActivityForResult`. The previous parent `Activity` should spawn the next one with this call. Data can be passed backwards via extras (`Bundle`) in an `Intent` when returning to the parent `Activity` in `onActivityResult` - or you can simply use the result codes.

You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities

Answer (score 0):

Better use with [onKeyDown.](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.in/2011/03/example-code-for-onkeydown-listener-in.html) & [onKeyDown Example](http://www.androiddevelopment.org/category/code-examples/)

Just override this android's default method. It'll provide the changes with whatever you want.